# Powershell script keeps running as "Dry run" and no changes are made

Tags: powershell

I found a simple PS script online to batch-edit a folder full of bookmarks to change their target (I moved a hard drive to another PC so the Local Network path changed.)

I installed PS and got it working, but every time I run the script (even as Admin), it starts with "**Dry Run**" at the top, the commands appear to execute w/o error, but when it's finished, I check to find no changes have been made.

What am I doing wrong? TIA

Comment: Please post the actual code you're running :-)

Comment: How about contacting the author of the script? How should we answer this question without knowing what the script does ... without seeing the actual code?

Comment: There's probably a variable at the top of that script, something like `$dryRun = $true`.. Search for that and set it to `$false`

Comment: What if there is a [`-WhatIf`](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/powershell-basics-don-t-fear-hitting-enter-with-whatif/ba-p/353579) switch involved?

Comment: Thx. I found "$dryRun = $TRUE" in the script and set it to $false. I don't know why the author put that in there. Very annoying.

Comment: The author put that in to be able to test the code without destroying anything first. Goes to show that you should **always** read code you downloaded first before you execute it.